# iPhone App display name

Tags: iphone, info.plist

If I have an iPhone app named: MyCoolApp

How do I keep the bundle named: MyCoolApp.app

But have the app name on that shows up underneath my icon read: My Cool App

I have changed my PRODUCT_NAME target setting to be "My Cool App" and changed my plist CFBundleDisplayName and CFBundleName to be "MyCoolApp".  So far my app name on the device still reads "My Cool App"

I'm pretty green to this stuff still.  Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes when changing the Project Properties it does not work. Project Properties and Target Properties Window look the same. I have mistaken there sooo many times. ;)

Comment: OK, I got it working.  It wasn't a project/target setting problem.  It looks like if I set the CFBundleDisplayName to "My Cool App" it gets set that way on the device correctly.  So I am leaving the PRODUCT_NAME alone and just setting CFBundleDisplayName.

Answer (score 5):

You might need to delete the app from the device and reload it for the change to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is using a key called Bundle Display Name. It has to be added in the info.plist.

DO NOT CHANGE THE PRODUCT NAME IN BUILD SETTINGS. 
This is not a good approach as it changes your bundle identifier. All you need to change is the product display label.

Note: Make sure to include this in info.plist in your projectTests info.plist also.

Comment: I cant add a photo as I just joined and stackoverflow does not allow me to post pictures!