# after changing the product Name, my code cannot run anymore in the simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode

In the project, Building Setting, I changed the product name from {Target Name} to something I like, but I found I cannot run the code in the simulator any more.

Anyone has similar experience before and how to solve it?

Comment: Go to the organizer in your Xcode, go to projects and delete the derived data of your project and clean the project then again build it.

Answer (score 0):

[The easiest thing to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258442/iphone-app-display-name) is change the "`CFBundleDisplayName`" property in the Info.plist file and leave your PRODUCT_NAME setting what it originally was (which was "`${TARGET_NAME}`").

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in my xcode project to test your situation. Yes you are right. the simulator started but project didn't run and debugger also didn't start. Finally i deleted my old application from simulator and run it again. it worked :)

> So just delete old application from simulator and Run it again. Its simple. I don't know about the reason but there could be bundle identifier mismatch with your target name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the old build from your simulator if you have changed the target name